# OpenVPN 2.4.3 connection issues with AES-256-GCM

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-14.04

I am using OpenVPN 2.4.3 and EasyRSA-3.0.1. My Tunnelblick connection fails with

```
cipher AES-256-GCM not found
```

even though it's listed in `openvpn --show-ciphers`

It works if I change it to use AES-256-CBC.

While OpenVPN will connect and I can ping with `compress lz4-v2`, ssh connections fail but will work when I use `comp-lzo`

Answer (score 1):

Click on the tunnelblick icon on the menu bar of Mac OSx and then go to vpn details it will show all the settings.
Now change OpenVPN version to 2.4.4-OpenSSL v1.0.2l
It will work.